# Refresh Page every X minutes after a button is submitted Javascript

Tags: javascript, refresh

I would like to Refresh page every X minutes after I "checked" a button. After I check again stop to refresh the page during this interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<script>
 setInterval(function(){
   location.reload();
 },60000);
</script>
```

1000 = 1 second

Answer (score 0):

Try below. You have to clear the interval when the checkbox is unchecked.

```
<input id='checkBox1' type='checkbox' onchange='handleChange(this);'>Checkbox

(function() {
  checkState = localStorage.getItem("checkState");
  if (checkState) {
    document.getElementById('checkBox1').click();
  }
})();

function handleChange(checkbox) {
  localStorage.setItem("checkState", checkbox.checked);

  if (checkbox.checked) {
    this.id = setInterval(function() {
      alert('checked');
      window.location.reload();
    }, 3000);
  } else {
    if (this.id) {
      clearInterval(this.id);
    }
  }
}
```

### Update 1

Sorry for the long delay. Since http is stateless, it does not retain the last known states of any elements that are in a page. It initializes all the elements with the defaults. The best possible we can do is use window.localStorage or widnow.sessionStorage. Local storage persists the value across browser restarts while session storage does not. I have updated the answer with local storage. Can you try the updated answer?

Comment: I appreciate your help, I confess it takes a long time i don't program for front end. It worked however it is unchecked after the refresh (expected). Do you know a way to persist it checked after the refresh.

Comment: @WendellLacerda, were you able to fix the issue using the code provided?